# The possibility to define a composite unique constraint for specific cases

Tags: mysql, database-design, unique-constraint

I have two tables: `user` and `address`.

User table:

| id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | henk@example.com | Henk |
| 2 | john@example.com | John |

Address table:

| id | user_id | street | is_default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Super cool street | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Beautiful avenue | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Some street | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | Damn cool street | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | Cool street | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | My street | 0 |

**The problem**

Image someone setting two default addresses for a user; it would be non-sensical from the Business logic perspective.

**The question**

I want to create a unique constraint composed by `user_id` and `is_default` but only for a specific case, which is that the constraint must be enforced when `is_default` is `1`.

Is this possible with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a foreign key column in the `user` table that references the primary key of the `address` table. Call it `default_address_id`. This enforces uniqueness because it can have only one value at a time for a given user.

Then drop the `is_default` column in your `address` table because it risks disagreeing with the foreign key in the `user` table.

Comment: I should've thought of that. It's that simple. Thanks for the rubber duck.